# internet Explorer 8 manage addon pop disabling

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8

How can I prevent "manage add-on pop up" coming up every time I start IE8. I tried following procedures and nothing helped.

1. Reset IE8 and reinstalled IE8 completely.
2. Disabled all add-on.

Is there any way I can change the add-on pop time or any registry or local group policy modification. This is a home laptop.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: This is off-topic here. It'll likely get migrated over to SU shortly, though.

Comment: Of course if you had read the FAQ you would already have been aware of that. Please take a moment to do so now.